# ActiveMerchant PaypalExpress gateway - set who is paying fees

Tags: activemerchant, paypal

I'm trying to create a Paypal express transaction using ActiveMerchant.  Is there any way to set the payee as the entity responsible of paying any Paypal fees accrued?

```
payment_hash = {
    ip: ip_address,
    return_url: ...,
    cancel_return_url: ...,
    currency: 'USD',
    locale: "en",
    brand_name: 'Store', 
    allow_guest_checkout: 'false',   #payment with credit card for non PayPal users
  }


  response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(@ad.subtotal, payment_hash)
```

In the PayPal documentation there's a note about a `feePayer` parameter that can be passed with the value of `SENDER` but it seems that it is not working when I add it to the `payment_hash` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `feePayer`isn't the right parameter name. According to [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) documentation, its correct name is `feesPayer`.

Comment: surprisingly, this is the right answer. i feel a little bit shamed. :) thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Don't worry, we all know this "What?! THAT was the problem all the time?!?!"-feeling. In this case I guess that the Paypal interface checks only for the parameters it knows - it just doesn't care if there is one that it doesn't know. So you'll get no error message even if you put `noodlesoup:'yummy'`there.